# How to remove an additional space from zsh auto complete function?

Tags: autocomplete, zsh

I use `compctl -K _my_cpl ls` to hook my auto complete function to `ls` command. The function returns a list of names from an index file.

However, zsh always adds a space after each completion. If I want to auto complete multiple level directory, I have to remove a space every time. **Is there a way to remove additional space just like the `-o nospace` option in bash complete command?**

I tested `zstyle ':completion:*' add-space false` command and it does not work. Thank you.

```
_my_cpl() {
local cur last opts

# current word in command line.
read -cA cur
last=$cur[-1]

# grep all directories and file names under current directory level.
opts=`egrep "${last}[^/]*[$|/]*" ~/index -o |uniq`

reply=($=opts)
}
compctl -K _my_cpl ls
```

Comment: zsh has a bashcompinit module. I can port my bash complete function to zsh as a work around.

autoload bashcompinit

bashcompinit

Answer (score 2):

```
compctl -K _my_cpl -S '' ls
```

This answers the question you asked, but it may not be flexible enough for what you want to do. In particular, this approach doesn't let you specify a different suffix for directories and regular files. If you want that, I think you need to switch to the “new” completion system and make separate calls to `compadd` with different `-S` arguments.